# Issue running multiple tasks that returns the same result

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the code bellow (is simplified to be readable). My issue is that the tasks in the list are totally identical as long as the return type is a value type (bool/int) and have the same value. The tasks are no longer equal if the result is a reference type (ex: bool?) or if for example would return different int values.

I don't understand why the tasks are equal even if they actually work properly (console logs all 6 values) , can someone please explain or point me to some documentation that would explain this.

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task RunMultipleTasks()
    {
        var list = new List<int> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        var tasks = list.Select(i => RunSimple(i)).ToList();
        var x = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Assert.IsTrue(tasks[0]== tasks[1]);  
    }

    private async Task<bool> RunSimple(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            return true;
        }
```

Also I noticed that task are no longer identical if I add a delay inside RunSimple method, or if I remove the async and return Task.FromResult(true)

Comment: Side note: `bool?` is not a reference type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tasks are cached for common use cases.

---

The state machine that the compiler generates when using the `async` keyword uses the `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<TResult>` struct. For common use case, such as returning `0` for numbers or `true` or `false` for bools it uses a cached task for performance reasons. The code for that can be found in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,a431f9d7dd423518,references).

---

This [blog post about ValueTasks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/07/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/) describes the behaviour in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

That's because RunSimple runs synchronously and returns a constant value. I think the compiler replaces it with one precalculated Task.
P.S. Task.FromResult(true) uses a TaskCompletionSource to create a new task each time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Instead of:

```
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

At the RunSimple() method.